# postgresql hibernate generated sequence in information_schema not shown in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, pgadmin

I generated database tables from java-hibernate(Spring-boot) and then copied the database to new server. Somehow some sequences are not shown in pgAdmin tool. The query I used is

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.sequences
```

But those sequences are there in the database and used by hibernate. So I can not recreate the same sequences. Following query shows those sequences.

```
SELECT c.* FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S' order by c.relname;
```

How do I get those sequences visible in pgAdmin?

Comment: What does `\d` show you from the pg admin console?  Is the Hibernate sequence visible there?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen \ds shows all the sequences created by hibernate. Just the PgAdmin UI tool doesn't show those sequences  under the schema -> sequences